# JS: OpenWeatherMap API returns "undefinded" for parameter "rain.3h"

Tags: javascript, php, json, api

I'd like to have some parameters from this API in my "home.php". 
I already got values for parameters cloud, min & max temp, wind etc. ...
But in case of rain.3h my console shows an error, because of the number "3" behind the point. So i put it into brackets and it returns now "undefinded". Do you have any suggestions to solve this problem? (Parameter rain is set for this JSON response because i see the value in the browser-console.
Here´s my code:

```
function getWeatherData(weatherlat, weatherlong) {
    var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=" + weatherlat + "&lon=" + weatherlong + "&units=metric&APPID=88e60f2ce52794ed240874b235f21794";

    $.ajax({
        url: url
    }).done(data => {
        let nextForecast = data.list[0].main;
        let cloudy = data.list[0].clouds;
        let weatherCond = data.list[0].weather[0];
        let windy = data.list[0].wind;
        let rainy = data.list[0].rain;
        console.log(data);

        $('#progressbar2').addClass('hidden');

        //"<img src='http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + data.weather[0].icon + ".png' alt='Icon depicting current weather.'>"
        document.getElementById("weathercond").innerHTML = `${weatherCond.description}`;
        document.getElementById("weathericon").innerHTML = "<img src='http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + weatherCond.icon + ".png' alt='Icon depicting current weather.'>"; 
        document.getElementById("cloud").innerHTML = `${cloudy.all}%`;
        document.getElementById("mintemp").innerHTML = `${nextForecast.temp_min}°C`;
        document.getElementById("maxtemp").innerHTML = `${nextForecast.temp_max}°C`;
        document.getElementById("luftftgk").innerHTML = `${nextForecast.humidity}%`;
        document.getElementById("windrtg").innerHTML = `${windy.deg}°`;
        document.getElementById("windspeed").innerHTML = `${windy.speed}m/s`;
        document.getElementById("rainfall").innerHTML = `${['rainy']['3h']}mm`;
    });
```

Comment: `['rainy']['3h']` -> `rainy['3h']`

Comment: It worked, thank you!!
`${rainy['3h']}mm`;